# How to redirect to another page laravel

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

I simply wrote few lines on the top of the page that if the session is not set then it should redirect to another page but it's not working it show the white screen and doesn't redirect to another page Here is the code.

```
session_start();
include('includedb2.php');
if(! isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
  return Redirect::to('front');
  exit;
}
```

I added it on the top of the page but it's not working

Comment: You use Laravel but still include files manually (even one for the db connection??), use native sessions and a custom authentication mechanism? What's even the point of using a framework then... I suggest you give the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) a good read and learn what the framework is capable of. Here are a few must reads: [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication), [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent), [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries), [Sessions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session)

Comment: is it not redirecting to another page because of this reason?

Comment: It likely is redirecting, you just aren't doing anything on that route.  What happens when you manually go to `yourapp.com/front` where yourapp.com is the entry point into your app?

Comment: `Route::get('front', function()
{
  
 return View::make('medical-view.frontpage');
});`

Comment: i have defined this root and it's working but in the case which i defined above it's not working :(

Comment: It seems like `$_SESSION['login_user']` is not set and the else case is not handled. An `else` block after the `if` (just simply echoing or something simple) can help you debug the situation more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I find that [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) isn't optimal when checking if a key in an array exists. Instead, why not use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check if `login_user` is in `$_SESSION` instead?

Additionally, your redirect syntax seems a little different from what I saw in Laravel's [redirect documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects).

Comment: it shows error when i use this `return redirect('user/login');` and the error is `Call to undefined function redirect()`